# How to learn making Multi Screen Apps using React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, shoutem

I am new to both `JavaScript` and `React Native`.

I've learned most of `React` and `React Native` and have built Apps using the knowledge too.

But all of those were *single screen ones*. But in the real world, 99% of the Apps require another page.

I browsed all over the `Internet` for tutorials.

I tried `Navigator`, `StackNavigator`, and a few more from many websites and YouTube videos.

*But I am always failing*.

The closest I came was with `Navigator`, which is now **deprecated**.

Also, I am using `@shoutem/ui` for most of the components, because it's just beautiful. And I prefer a custom `Navigation Bar` for all of my apps because the native navigation bar of `iOS` is really ugly. This custom navigation bar is also taken by `@shoutem/ui`.

Thus, to summarise,

> I want to learn how to make multi screen Apps with Stack Navigator,
>   and custom `Navigation Bar` from `@shoutem/ui`.
>
> Can someone please explain it here or send a good link? It would be
>   really helpful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation. Inside there is an example. Good luck!